# DOM traversing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a comparison overlay that shows items selected by users when they 'add to compare' link.(like one in [flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com) that appears on top when you hit add to compare). Here is my code:

```
<div class="college-list-container">
  <div class = "individual-college-container" id="text1">
    <div class="image-header"><h3>text1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <a href=""><div class="overlay-links" style=" float:left;"> <div class="absolute-center ">Details</div></div></a>     
      <a href=""> <div class="overlay-links" style=" float:right; border-right:none;"> <div class="absolute-center comparison" id="comparison">Add to compare</div>
      </div></a>
    </div>       
  </div>
  <div class = "individual-college-container">
    <div class="image-header"><h3>text2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <a href=""><div class="overlay-links" style=" float:left;"> <div class="absolute-center ">Details</div></div></a>     
      <a href=""> <div class="overlay-links" style=" float:right; border-right:none;"> <div class="absolute-center comparison">Add to             compare</div>
      </div></a>
    </div>       
  </div>

  <div class = "individual-college-container" id="itm">
    <div class="image-header" ><h3>text3</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="dark-overlay">
      <a href=""><div class="overlay-links" style=" float:left;"> <div class="absolute-center ">Details</div></div></a>     
      <a href=""> <div class="overlay-links" style=" float:right; border-right:none;"> <div class="absolute-center comparison">Add to             compare</div>
      </div></a>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
/show overlay when one checkbox is checked and add its name/image to the empty space
  $('.comparison').click(function(e){
     var clgId = $(this).parentsUntil('.individual-clg-container').find('.image-header').text();
     e.preventDefault();
     var clg = $("<li></li>")
     clg.text(clgId);
     var removeLink = $("<a href=''>(Remove)</a>");
     clg.append(removeLink)
     $('.comparison-colleges').append(clg);
     $('.add-to-compare-overlay').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300);

  });
```

I want the text in the div containing class 'image-header' to be assigned to the variable clgId. The problem that i am facing with my code is that it is adding the text of all the divs containing class 'image-header'. Ex i want the value text1 to be assigned on clicking add to compare of the div with id text1. However it assigns 'text1 text2 text3' to clgId.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a JSFiddle with what I think is your desired functionality (I included a console log output in the script of the `clgId` variable):

http://jsfiddle.net/py38kuvv/

I replaced the `parentsUntil` function with the `closest` function (and replaced the `individual-clg-container` class selector):

```
var clgId = $(e.target).closest('.individual-college-container').find('.image-header').text();
```

and also updated your click handler:

```
$('.comparison').on( "click", function(e) {
```

In order to get a quicker response in future, posting a JSFiddle of what you have so far makes it easier for others to help :)

Comment: thank you for the answer. That solved my problem. And i will make sure i post a JSFiddle next time i have a problem

Comment: I wanted to ask if it would make a difference if i used $(this) instead of $(e.target). Also please tell me which should be used when.

Comment: In this case you could use $(this), I tend to use $(e.target) on event handlers and $(this) in other instances. Both options allow you to target one element specifically. If the answer helped, feel free to accept it :)

Comment: For more information on $(this), check out JavaScript function context - that is what determines what `this` is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

It is adding all of them because

```
var clgId = $(this).parentsUntil('.individual-clg-container').find('.image-header').text();
```

should be

```
var clgId = $(this).parentsUntil('.individual-college-container').find('.image-header').text();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This did not work however for some reason. Another error in my code i guess.